# Call a function with variable (with checkbox)

Tags: function, powershell, checkbox

I am pretty new to powershell. I just created a GUI with powershell studio (by the way nice product!) and my code works perfectly. But I don't like the "look" of my programming. As I want to learn here is what I fail to do:

When I click a button I have this that work :

```
if ($checkbox1.Checked -eq $true )
{   
    (Get-WmiObject -Computer $table[0] Win32_Service -Filter "Name='TlntSvr'").InvokeMethod("StopService",$null)
    $serv = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName $table[0]     | ? { $_.name -like "tlntSvr" } )
    $tel1.text = $serv.state

    if ($serv.state = "Running" )
        {$tel1.backcolor = 'Chartreuse'}
    else
        {$tel1.backcolor = 'Red'}
}
```

What it does, it check if a checkbox have been ticked or not and if the checkbox is ticked, then it stops the telnet service and then display on my gui the new status. Again that work fine.

My problem is I have 8 checkboxes (named $checkbox1, $checkbox2 ....). And so I have 8 times the code you see there, once with checkbox1, once with checkbox2 etc. Same for the varibale $tel, which is a display field that change in each "if" (for checkbox 1, I need to update tel1, for checkbox2, I need to update tel2 etc.).

How can I simplify this and make a function call? I know how to use fonction, but here in the function the stuf you do are not on the same variable (once on checkbox1, once on checkbox2).

How can I make this more "clean"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do something along the lines of this:

First you would create new variables for the specifics that change for each iteration of a checkbox (#1 through #8). In the quick example below, I created variables for the 'service' and the 'tel' from your original code.

Afterward the variables are defined, you would hit the main process, which utilizes the new variables you defined. This way you would have less code to look at and becomes easier to manage.

```
# Setting Variables
if ($checkbox1.checked -eq $true)
{
    $service = TlntSvr
    $tel = $tel1
}
elseif ($checkbox2.checked -eq $true)
{
    $service = OtherService
    $tel = $tel2
}
elseif ($checkbox3.checked -eq $true)
{
    etc...
}

# Main Process
(gwmi -Computer $table[0] Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$service'").InvokeMethod("StopService",$null)
$serv = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -ComputerName $table[0]     | ? { $_.name -like "'$service'" } )
$tel.text = $serv.state

if ($serv.state = "Running" )
    {$tel.backcolor = 'Chartreuse'}
else
    {$tel.backcolor = 'Red'}
}
```